# Having trouble uploading image into pygame

Tags: image, upload, pygame

I am trying to understand why when I create instances of my class Picture that the file will not load. I have put the file cartizzle.png in the same directory but I keep getting an error saying:  error: couldn't open cartizzle.png

```
class Picture():    

    def __init__(self, location, filename):
        self.x = location[0]
        self.y = location[1]
        self.filename = filename

    def draw(self):
        pygame.init()
        surface_sz = 500
        main_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((surface_sz, surface_sz))

    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.poll()
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        elif ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_q:
            break           
        main_surface.fill((0,200,255))
        main_surface.blit(self.filename, (self.x, self.y))               
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

pic_inst = Picture((150,200), pygame.image.load("cartizzle.png"))
pic_inst.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should intend the 'while true' into the draw() function.

```
class Picture():

def __init__(self, location, filename):
    self.x = location[0]
    self.y = location[1]
    self.filename = filename

def draw(self):
    pygame.init()
    surface_sz = 500
    main_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((surface_sz, surface_sz))

    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.poll()
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        elif ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ev.key == pygame.K_q:
            break
        main_surface.fill((0,200,255))
        main_surface.blit(self.filename, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

pic_inst = Picture((150,200), pygame.image.load("cartizzle.png"))
pic_inst.draw()
```

This will make it work. It made it work for me, I got an error message when trying to run your code.